# return byte array with Arduino

Tags: memory, arduino, dynamic-memory-allocation, static-memory-allocation

I have an array that contains `bytes` of information (a payload), but I want to use this array in two functions. How can I return it? I don't know if I have to declare it different or in other place.

My code:

```
void loop() {
    byte payload[] = find_fix();
    delay(5*60000);
}


byte find_fix(){
    byte payload[9];

    double lati = sodaq_gps.getLat();
    double longi = sodaq_gps.getLon();
    int nsatis = sodaq_gps.getNumberOfSatellites();
    long lax = lati * 10000000;
    long lox = longi * 10000000;

    payload[0] = (byte) ((lax & 0xFF000000) >> 24 );
    payload[1] = (byte) ((lax & 0x00FF0000) >> 16 );
    payload[2] = (byte) ((lax & 0x0000FF00) >> 8 );
    payload[3] = (byte) ((lax & 0X000000FF));
    payload[4] = (byte) ((lox & 0xFF000000) >> 24 );
    payload[5] = (byte) ((lox & 0x00FF0000) >> 16 );
    payload[6] = (byte) ((lox & 0x0000FF00) >> 8 );
    payload[7] = (byte) ((lox & 0X000000FF));
    payload[8] = (byte) (nsatis);
    SerialUSB.print(" MIGUEL. LATITUD: ");
    SerialUSB.print(payload[0], HEX);
    SerialUSB.print(payload[1], HEX);
    SerialUSB.print(payload[2], HEX);
    SerialUSB.println(payload[3], HEX);
    SerialUSB.print(" MIGUEL. LONGITUD: ");
    SerialUSB.print(payload[4], HEX);
    SerialUSB.print(payload[5], HEX);
    SerialUSB.print(payload[6], HEX);
    SerialUSB.println(payload[7], HEX);
    SerialUSB.print(" MIGUEL. Num Sats: ");
    SerialUSB.println(payload[8], HEX);

    return payload[];
}
```

I want to use 9 bytes of information, first I declare it `byte payload[9];` and then I start writing on it. This works well, but now I want to return it for use it in another functions but I can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't return stack allocated memory from a function. Once the function call ends that data will be reclaimed when the stack pointer is updated. You need to either dynamically allocate the memory on the heap like so ...

```
byte* find_fix(){
    byte* payload = new byte[9]; // Allocate memory on the heap

    return payload;
}

void loop() {
    byte* payload = find_fix();
    delete[] payload; // Free memory once it is no longer needed
}
```

Or if you know the max size of the array, you can pass in memory to the `find_fix` function like so ...

```
void find_fix(byte* payload) {
    ....
}

void loop() {
    byte payload[9];
    find_fix(payload);
}
```

Comment: How I know the max size I'm using your second option, but appears this error `invalid conversion from 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'uint32_t {aka long unsigned int}' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: How are you calling the function? The compiler is upset that the `find_fix(byte* payload)` is expecting a `byte* {aka unsigned char*}` parameter but you are providing a `uint32_t`

Comment: `find_fix(payload);` the same as you put

Comment: I just compiled a test program ... 
`#include <stdio.h>

void find_fix(unsigned char* payload) {
    printf("%x\n", payload[0]);
}

int main() {
    unsigned char payload[9];
    payload[0] = 0xFF;
    find_fix(payload);
    return 0;
}` with `$ gcc -Wall test.c -o test` and it works just fine. Must be something with the code. What type is the payload variable. Maybe change it to unsigned char?